# Fitting Spark ML Kmeans for subsets or groups of data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I've got a Dataset where each Row is a (class: String, vectors: Array[Array[Float]]), and I'd like to fit a kmeans model in Spark MLLib per class.  I can explode the vectors to normalize the data, loop through the classes, filter the entire dataset by class, and fit a model per iteration of the loop, but that's horribly inefficient (although it's how Spark does it in the fit method of the OneVsRest classifier here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/OneVsRest.scala).

Here's a snippet that accomplishes this with a ParArray, inspired by OneVsRest's approach:

```
val classes = normalized_data.select("class").distinct.map(_.getString(0)).collect
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(5)

val models = classes.par.map { class =>
  val training_data = unpacked_data.filter($"label" === class)
  val model = kmeans.fit(training_data)
  (class, model)
}
```

It seems that the KMeans fit method needs the data to be a Dataset with one-row-per-vector, which suggests normalizing / exploding the data, but what's the best way to go about this?  Can't I somehow leverage the fact that I start with all of my data points in each row and/or group on the label to use just these points without explicitly filtering the entire dataset for every class I want to build a model for?

PS- I know KMeans.fit actually needs org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector; presume I've transformed my Array[Float] accordingly.

Comment: Did you find any solution of this problem?

Comment: KMeans seams to be a clustering algorithms in Spark ML, not a classification algorithm. There is LinearSVC classification and few ProbabilisticClassifier in Spark